# Cocos2d iPhone Game Remove menu from scene

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have written a few games using Cocos2d iPhone. In all of my previous games I would change scenes when I setup a **CCMenu** and then leave that scene when I was finished. In my current project, I need the menu to exist in my current scene and be able to open and then close the menu many times. For some reason, I can't seem to understand, *removeChild* will not remove the menu. I have seen several examples online that show using removeChild, but it does not work for me. Below is my menu code, when the Start/CreateNewAccount button is pressed I want the current menu to be removed from the scene completely.

This is in my init method.

```
     CCMenuItemImage *Start = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"MakeLemonade.png" selectedImage:@"MakeLemonadePressed.png"
                                                            target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(CreateNewAccount:)];
     CCMenuItemImage *About = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"About.png" selectedImage:@"AboutPressed.png"
                                                            target:self
                                                            selector:@selector(About:)];
     Start.position = ccp(-175, -90);
     About.position = ccp(175, -90);

     CCMenu *MainMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: Start, About, nil];
    [Start runAction:[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:1.0]];
    [About runAction:[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:1.0]];
     [self addChild:MainMenu z:6];

}
return self;
}
-(void) BeginMenuLayer {

//this is not working


[self removeChild:MainMenu cleanup:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your init method you've declared MainMenu as a local variable.  You're not setting it as a property, so you don't have a reference when you go to remove it later.

1) Make sure you have a property declared for it like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCMenu *MainMenu;
```

2) Synthesize it at the top of your implementation:

```
@synthesize MainMenu;
```

3) Make sure you release it in your dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    self.MainMenu = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

4) When you construct it, assign it to your property rather than a local variable:

```
self.MainMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: Start, About, nil];
```

Now you have a retained reference to the object, which you can pass later to `removeChild:cleanup:`.

Comment: You don't NEED to set it up as a property. An iVar would be enough. Just thought I'd clarify that.

Comment: This is true.  It just requires extra diligence to avoid leaking memory when you do ivar assignments.

Comment: Yes or you could assign it a tag and removeChildByTag.